# SQL Server sum function not correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have tried searching but cannot find any answer.

The question is: I have a table with columns `ID, PC, BALANCE, SRC_TYPE`.

The `src_type` can be either 00 or 02.

When it's 00, all the balances will show along with the final summed up balances for 002 an example below:

```
PC   BALANCE  SRC_TYPE
----------------------
1234  10        00
1234  20        00
1234  30        00
1234  60        02
```

From the example `SRC_TYPE` or 02 holds the total balance whilst `SRC_TYPE` of 00 holds the amounts and if summed together will equal the full balance as per 02.

I have tried but not been successful all I want to achieve as an out output is

```
PC   BALANCE BALANCE SRC_TYPE
------------------------------
1234  60      60       02
```

I want to show the summed up balance against the total balance, I am stuck.

I used

```
SELECT PC, SUM(BALANCE), BALANCE, SRC_TYPE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PC, BALANCE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select pc, 
    sum(case when scr_type = '00' then balance end) balance_00,
    sum(case when scr_type = '02' then balance end) balance_02
from mytable
group by pc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
select *
from(
   select distinct  pc, sum(balance) over(partition by src) as by_src,sum(balance) over() as Total, src
   from Table
)a
where a.src = '02'
```